# Mysql, how disable connection for specific database

Tags: mysql, database

On my server (mysql 5.6) I have few databases, and one i moved to other server.
How can I disable acces to this one specific database on old server, but without drop it ?

Comment: Change the password - or enforce password connection if you don't already have it.

Comment: I don't think this is the best way. In postgresql I can just disable access to specific database. It possible that in mysql i can't?